# Drawn line - picking up random point on it

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, graphics, polygon

I am using JavaScript to draw on HTML Canvas.

I have a polygon represented as array of **[x,y]** coordinates. In my situation (game focused on expanding player's area) I want periodically expand the area represented by the polygon. I have two random possibilities - expand one of existing vertexes, or split one of the line.

My method works kinda good, but I have problem with splitting the lines. I can pick random line (or to be more precise two random neighboring polygons) and I can insert new polygon into my array of polygons. That works fine.

To find where the new polygon shall be, I tried to use **midpoint formula**. In my code it goes like this:

```
var x_mid = Math.round((globalMap[v1][0] + globalMap[v2][0]) / 2);
var y_mid = Math.round((globalMap[v1][1] + globalMap[v2][1]) / 2);
```

But I found it is not always picking up the correct spot on the line. Sometimes it ends up inside my polygon, which is a problem, because for expansion, my script is looking for free (not colored) pixels around and it finds none here.

I blame the **round()** function, but can't figure out how to make sure, I end up on the line that is actually drawn on canvas?

It doesn't have to be exact middle of the line, if someone knows other technique, it just needs to be somewhere on the edge, so it can expand later without flaws. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bit hard to know what you want. Round will give you the closet integer coordinates to the line and thus will give you coordinates above or below the line. But that is the nature of a line, it does not respect pixel coordinates. Maybe you could use lines in the form `(Math.floor(x/m))+c` where m is the number of x steps to move up or down a pixel. This would define the line as a set of (integer) pixel coordinates

Comment: You could also check these neighboring pixels for your desired condition: [x+1,y], [x-1,y], [x,y+1], [x,y-1], [x+1,y+1], [x-1,y+1], [x+1,y-1], [x-1,y-1].